# Need help to Fixing purchase event in GA4 and GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have made a GA4 property to pair with my Universal Analytics but I'm having difficulties with the set up of the ecommerce events.

I have read this [Official Guide](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10119380?hl=en) made by google in order to correctly configure the parameters of the event since the datalayer structure for GA4 is slightly different.

My data layer for the purchase has the following structure:

```
{
  "event": "purchase",
  "ecommerce": {
    "currencyCode": "EUR",
    "purchase": {
      "actionField": {
        "id": "XX7000294103",
        "affiliation": "",
        "revenue": "97.8000",
        "tax": "0.0000",
        "shipping": "0.0000",
        "shipping-term": "3 day shipping",
        "payment-term": "msp_cashondelivery2",
        "action": "purchase"
      },
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "Product Name",
          "id": "7263",
          "price": "89.90",
          "quantity": 1,
          "dimension2": "available",
          "dimension3": "0%"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and my purchase event has the following structure:

**TAG TYPE:** Google Analytics: GA4 Event
**EVENT NAME:** purchase

**EVENT PARAMETERS:**
Parameter Name

items: {{items}
transaction_id: {{Transaction_ID}}
currency: EUR
value: {{transaction_revenue}}

**TRIGGERING**
Custom Event

**Event name**
purchase

This Trigger fires on
All Custom Events
Event Name: purchase
|
|
|
|
|
|
**Variables:**
{{transaction_revenue}}  -> DATALAYERVARIABLE
ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue

{{Transaction_ID}} ->
DATALAYERVARIABLE
ecommerce.purchase.actionField.id

{{items} -> EEC Products -> GA4 Items (taken by the templates made by simo ahava)

I have made so far these events:

**add_to_cart**  Working
purchase 
checkout 
product_click 
remove_from_cart

Any idea why in GA4 I can only see the items added to cart but no purchases?